# Call from Plain JavaScript to Angular Service to Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using `$rootScope.$emit()` for raising events from service to controller.

It is working fine when emitting from the instance of service that is referenced in controller but $rootScope.$on is not getting called when emitting from the instance of service I got from angular injector in plain javascript .

Following is my code

**Plain JavaScript**

```
    var msgHandlerJS = function () {
    var injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'services']);
    var aMsgHandlerService = injector.get('msgHandlerService');

    aMsgHandlerService.TestScopeWatch();
}
```

Calling the above when dom is ready :

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {    
    msgHandlerJS();
});
```

**Service**

```
(function (module) {    

    var msgHandlerService = function ($rootScope, $http, $q, $timeout) {  
        var TestScopeWatch = function () {
            $http.get('~/test.json').then(function (result) {
                EmailPacket = result.data.Packet;

                $rootScope.$emit("EmailPacketChanged", EmailPacket);     
            });
        };

        return {
            //making public
            TestScopeWatch:TestScopeWatch,
        };
    };

    module.factory("msgHandlerService", ["$rootScope","$http", "$q","$timeout", msgHandlerService]);

}(angular.module("services")));
```

**Controller**

```
(function (module) {   
    function testController($rootScope,$scope, msgHandlerService) {
        $rootScope.$on("EmailPacketChanged", function(event,data){
            alert('Here I am');
        };
    };

    module.controller("testController", ["$rootScope","$scope", "msgHandlerService",  testController]);    

}(angular.module('app')));
```

Comment: @pherris  It is working fine when emitting from the instance of service that is referenced in controller but $rootScope.$on is not getting called when emitting from the instance of service I got from angular injector in plain javascript .

Comment: @kumaro, can you provide your hrml?

Comment: Did you confirm that you are executing $rootScope.$emit?

Comment: Do you have an ng-app on the page?

Comment: @pherris Yes, emit  is executing . I see a network call to get test.json

Comment: seems like `$rootScope` in service and in controller - different

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to get the proper injector of the application, **[`angular.injector`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.injector)** creates a new injector, it has nothing to do with the injector that bootstrapped your app. So the instance of the service (yourService, rootScope inside it) you get from that injector is different instance than what is in the app. You should instead use the getter **[`.injector()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#jquery-jqlite-extras)** from the **[`rootElement`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootElement)** of the application.

i.e if you have an `ng-app` or manually bootstrapping, get the injector out of that element. Example:

```
 var injector = angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-app]')).injector();
```

If your app root is document (`html`) then get injector from the `document` i.e :

```
var injector = angular.element(document).injector()
```

Also if you want any scope bindings to reflect you also need to invoke a digest cycle (alert will work fine ofcourse):

```
var msgHandlerJS = function() {
   var injector = angular.element(document).injector();
   var aMsgHandlerService = injector.get('msgHandlerService');
   var $rootScope = injector.get('$rootScope');
   aMsgHandlerService.TestScopeWatch();
   $rootScope.$digest();
}
```

```js
(function(module) {

  var msgHandlerService = function($rootScope, $http, $q, $timeout) {
    var TestScopeWatch = function() {
      //$http.get('~/test.json').then(function(result) {
      //  EmailPacket = result.data.Packet;

      $rootScope.$emit("EmailPacketChanged", {});
      // });
    };

    return {
      //making public
      TestScopeWatch: TestScopeWatch,
    };
  };

  module.factory("msgHandlerService", ["$rootScope", "$http", "$q", "$timeout", msgHandlerService]);

}(angular.module("services", [])));

(function(module) {
  function testController($rootScope, $scope, msgHandlerService) {
    $rootScope.$on("EmailPacketChanged", function(event, data) {
      $scope.got = "got the message!!";
    });
  }

  module.controller("testController", ["$rootScope", "$scope", "msgHandlerService", testController]);

}(angular.module('app', ['services'])));

var msgHandlerJS = function() {

  var injector = angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-app]')).injector();
  var aMsgHandlerService = injector.get('msgHandlerService');
  var $rootScope = injector.get('$rootScope');
  aMsgHandlerService.TestScopeWatch();
  $rootScope.$digest();
}
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  msgHandlerJS();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="test" ng-app="app" ng-controller="testController">
  {{got}}
</div>
```

Comment: @PSL Thanks bro!  It's the injector. I think I am creating a new one instead of using the existing one.   following line fixed it `angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-app]')).injector();`

Comment: @kumaro yes you are.. That injector has nothing to with the one bootstrapped your application... So it is like you are invoking method on a different instance of the service.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that. Now that I know it makes more sense. Is it the fastest way to get injector ?  Not sure if query selector goes through each & every element looking for 'ng-app'  and slow down the application

Comment: @kumaro where is your ng-app? on the html? Also see my answer update with links to official documentations.

Comment: @PSL It's on a div further down

Comment: @kumaro put an id for the div and select it with the id (`document.getElementById`), If you are looking at micro optimization with attribute selection. But using attribute selector is not that bad as well but will be slower (very minute you wont even notice) than id for sure.

Comment: @PLS  I will do testing and figure it out ... Thanks again !

Comment: @kumaro Sure!! np. Cheers!!